# ¿Cuál es un equivalente para "it follows" en español?

Tags: traducción, matemáticas

¿Cuál es un equivalente para "it follows" en español?

Caso de uso:

> Since x is greater than 2, it follows that x is greater than 1.

Y la traducción:

> Dado que x es mayor que 2, ____ x es mayor que 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Matemáticas usamos mucho la palabra `luego`:

> x es mayor que 2, **luego** x es mayor que 1.

Nótese que he eliminado la primera parte de "dado que", pues no es usada con demasiada frecuencia.

Así, queda una frase sintética y concisa.

De la RAE:

> [**luego**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=40pwijFHEDXX2zwZF1ps)
>
> 5. conj. ilat. Por consiguiente, por lo tanto. *Pienso, luego existo. ¿Luego era fundado mi temor?*

Answer (score 4):

Podrías usar:

> Dado que *x* es mayor que 2, `entonces`/`tenemos que` *x* es mayor que 1.

Otra forma sería:

> *X* es mayor que 2, por lo tanto *x* es mayor que 1.

Podrías incluso omitir un sustituto de `it follows`, así:

> Dado que x es mayor que 2, x es mayor que 1.

Answer (score 2):

Ambas respuestas son correctas, para generalizar se aceptan todas las conjunciones de consecuencia, en varios libros de matemáticas se usa tanto *luego*, *entonces*, *por lo que*, *lo que implica que*,...

Algunos ejemplos: http://www.gramaticas.net/2010/10/ejemplos-de-conjuncion-consecutiva.html

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo... pero no del todo : ) Como cualquier ciencia, las matemáticas tienen un lenguaje propio que hace que no todas las conjunciones consecutivas sean "bienvenidas" con igual efusividad. Por el contrario, las fórmulas suelen ser bastante estándar y de ahí que mencionara "luego" como la usada. Al menos esa es la que yo siempre vi durante mi licenciatura.

Answer (score 2):

En lógica proposicional se aceptan diferentes fórmulas.

- Para introducir la premisa *(since)*: «puesto que», «dado que», «porque», «ya que»...
- Para introducir la conclusión *(it follows)*: «luego», «por lo tanto», «por ende»...

Traducir literalmente *it follows* por «se sigue» es aceptable, [según veo](http://www.iesseneca.net/iesseneca/IMG/pdf/tema_7_logica.pdf).